# How to make something like this in HTML?

Tags: html, css, image

Something similar to this:

[image]

Just an image and a link to somewhere.

Here's something I whipped up, but can't seem to make it work as the picture.

http://jsfiddle.net/stapiagutierrez/z6LBL/6/

```
#portrait {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

#portrait .image {
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

#portrait a {
    float:right;
}

<div id="portrait">
    <img class="image" src="http://media.giantbomb.com/uploads/14/141112/1983897-307865_10150294906295771_529235770_8254698_904096888_n_large.jpg" />
    <a href="#">alterar foto</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/z6LBL/18/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use `position:relative` on the container and `position:absolute` on your anchor. Because the anchor is inside a `position:relative` box, it's top, left, right, and bottom properties are relative to the portrait div and not the whole page. Check out [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for more detail about the position property.

Answer (score 3):

you can use floats like you had, but i think absolute positioning is actually easier. @ least for me. here's your fiddle how you wanted it: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/z6LBL/19/

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to your portrait a css:

```
#portrait a {
    float:right;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -75px;
}
```

edit: just saw steveax's comment, you should probably use that. at least get's my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in that you need to have the img tag inside of the a tag., for example:

```
<a href="#">
<img class="image" src="http://media.giantbomb.com/uploads/14/141112/1983897-307865_10150294906295771_529235770_8254698_904096888_n_large.jpg" /
</a>
```

Also you may consider adding:

```
a {
border: 0;
}
```

To your style, if not, there will be a box around the image in Internet Explorer.

Edit: Yes, steveax is correct. I did not even think about you wanting the link inside the picture.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/z6LBL/37/

No floats are required.
Reorder the  and  then you can use this css:

```
#portrait {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

#portrait .image {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

#portrait a {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**UPDATE**: I didn't notice that you wanted a background color on this, you need to add a span around the  and style that separately.

http://jsfiddle.net/z6LBL/39/

```
<div id="portrait">
    <span>
     <a href="#">alterar foto</a>
    </span>
    <img class="image" src="http://media.giantbomb.com/uploads/14/141112/1983897-307865_10150294906295771_529235770_8254698_904096888_n_large.jpg" />
</div>
#portrait {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

#portrait .image {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

#portrait span {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}

#portrait a {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```